# How to transform an unbounded oscillator into a bounded oscillator between 0 and 100?

Tags: pine-script

do you know how to turn an unlimited oscillator into an limited oscillator between 0 and 100?

For example how to bound the Momentum indicator

```
mom = close - close[10]
plot(mom, color=#2962FF, title="MOM")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `normalize()` function that is explained [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-rescale-an-indicator-from-one-scale-to-another).

```
// ————— When the scale of the signal to rescale is unknown (unbounded).
// Min/Max of signal to rescale is determined by its historical low/high.
normalize(_src, _min, _max) =>
    // Normalizes series with unknown min/max using historical min/max.
    // _src      : series to rescale.
    // _min, _min: min/max values of rescaled series.
    var _historicMin =  10e10
    var _historicMax = -10e10
    _historicMin := min(nz(_src, _historicMin), _historicMin)
    _historicMax := max(nz(_src, _historicMax), _historicMax)
    _min + (_max - _min) * (_src - _historicMin) / max(_historicMax - _historicMin, 10e-10)
```